# How to split a string of address and fetching city , state, country and zip code?

Tags: c#, .net

eg. JBB Inc. Headquarters 20 West RiverCenter Blvd Covington KY 41011 USA

Comment: Required steps:
1. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
2. Try something yourself.
3. Come back and edit your question with things you've tried so far.
4. Wait for a response.

This question is exactely: How to NOT ask a question on SO.

Comment: Did you google it first?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Split method of the string.
ex: Address.Split(" ".ToCharArray()) // Address is a property of type string.

Answer (score 0):

Addresses are all so vastly different that you will never simply be able to split a string into the correct parts.  Rather capture the address as separate fields, or at least have comma's to separate fields.

If your addresses seem to be captured in a similar format you could create a function in code that could solve the majority (but probably not all) rows.